# Globally add "<@Assembly>" and "<@Import Namespace>" to Asp.net MVC views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration

Instead of writing

```
<@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
```

on every view I create I know I can easily just edit my `web.config` file and add this:

```
...
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

But this doesn't seem to work in design time. Visual Studio 2010 is not able to see `SPContext` unless I add these two lines on top of my view as well:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
```

So how do I add assemblies globally as well as import namespaces so VS will be able to resolve classes/objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add the assembly to the `<assemblies>` section of the `<compilation>` section under `<system.web>`:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add 
      assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Your `targetFramework` and `debug` attribute values may vary according to the framework version you're targetting and whether you're debugging or not.

Comment: Thought so myself and added it (well it was already added anyway). I only had to add namespace in `<pages>` element, but VS doesn't recognize `SPContext`.

Comment: Thanks anyway. It does work as expected. the problem was, that global web.config was not part of my Asp.net MVC so I had to redefine <compilation><add assemby> andd it started working in Visual Studio as well. Stupid of me. Thanks anyway. I have to wait a few more minutes to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you add the assembly in the Web.config, too.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Kev's answer was more complete so I accepted his and upvoted yours as well, since you did provide correct info.